# Unable to access the jsp page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I just started using spring boot and JSP  on IntelliJ idea using gradle as a build tool.When i run the application I see **404 error on browser** and on server console log i see the following message - **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'**

I tried a lot and could not able to find out what is the RCA for the above mentioned issue. Can some one help me by out looking into the code repository : https://github.com/vmaramreddy1/spring-jsp-setup

Comment: need your project structure and your configuration and controller code

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the resources in your 'web' directory to the 'src/main/webapp' directory. That's where Spring is expecting the views to be found.